# Why child component became shorter?

Tags: react-native

My project is a Animated view based on PanResponder.
The Animated.View has three child components.

When I dragged the animated view to top(and child component out of sight of the screen),the child content became shorter and shorter.

But no problem when dragged to bottom.

What is the matter,please?
Thanks!

=======

screen shot videos:

[drag child: no problem](https://youtu.be/iiD69zqfdbo)

[drag child: Problem occur when dragging](https://youtu.be/qoXHpZdMRh8)

=====

source:

complete code:

[drag panel](https://github.com/monkingame/test/blob/master/TestPanResponder/stage/DragNew1.js)

[child component](https://github.com/monkingame/test/blob/master/TestPanResponder/stage/ChildContent.js)

main codes shown:

```
    <View style={styles.draggableContainer}>
      <Animated.View
        onLayout={this.onLayout}
        {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
        style={[
          this.pan.getLayout(),
          styles.aniView,
        ]}>
        {this.renderChildren()}
      </Animated.View>
    </View>



renderChildren = () => {
  const { source } = this.state;
  const children = source.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <View key={item.toString()}
        style={{
          width: WIDTH,
          height: HEIGHT / 3,
          flex: 1,
          borderWidth: 1,
        }}>
        <ChildContent title={item} />
      </View>
    );
  });
  return children;
}

componentWillMount() {
  this.pan.addListener((value) => {
    this._value = value;
  });
  this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => ((gestureState.dx != 0) && (gestureState.dy != 0)),
    onPanResponderGrant: (e, gestureState) => {
      this.pan.setOffset({ x: this._value.x, y: this._value.y });
      this.pan.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 });
    },
    onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null, {
      dx: this.pan.x,
      dy: this.pan.y,
    }]),
    onPanResponderRelease: (e, gesture) => {
      this.pan.flattenOffset();
      this.animatePanel();
    }
  });
}
```

Environment:
OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution:

update to react-native 0.56.
(using  react-native-git-upgrade ,and update  babel-preset-react-native to 5.0.2).

then the problem disappeared.